# How can I highlight cells with categorical variables?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, background-color, pandas-styles

I have a pandas dataframe called value_matrix_classification which looks as follows:

```
{('wind_on_share',
  'Wind-onshore power generation'): {('AIM/CGE 2.0',
   'ADVANCE_2020_WB2C'): 'high', ('AIM/CGE 2.0',
   'ADVANCE_2030_Price1.5C'): 'high', ('AIM/CGE 2.0',
   'ADVANCE_2030_WB2C'): 'high', ('IMAGE 3.0.1',
   'ADVANCE_2020_WB2C'): 'low', ('IMAGE 3.0.1',
   'ADVANCE_2030_WB2C'): 'low', ('MESSAGE-GLOBIOM 1.0',
   'ADVANCE_2020_WB2C'): 'low'},
 ('wind_off_share',
  'Wind-offshore power generation'): {('AIM/CGE 2.0',
   'ADVANCE_2020_WB2C'): nan, ('AIM/CGE 2.0',
   'ADVANCE_2030_Price1.5C'): nan, ('AIM/CGE 2.0',
   'ADVANCE_2030_WB2C'): nan, ('IMAGE 3.0.1',
   'ADVANCE_2020_WB2C'): 'low', ('IMAGE 3.0.1',
   'ADVANCE_2030_WB2C'): 'low', ('MESSAGE-GLOBIOM 1.0',
   'ADVANCE_2020_WB2C'): 'low'}}
```

The two columns in the right contain `low, medium and high` which are categorical variables. I created them using `pd.cut(value_matrix_classification, bins = 3, labels = ["low", "medium", "high"]`

I'd like to highlight the pandas dataframe such that there are red, orange, yellow and  background color for high, medium, low and NaN values respectively.

I wrote the following function

```
def highlight_cells(x):
    if x == "high":
        color = "red"
    elif x=="medium":
        color = "orange"
    elif x=="low":
        color = "yellow"
    else:
        color = "gray"
    
    return [f"background-color: {color}"]
```

and applied it to the dataframe

```
value_matrix_classification.style.apply(highlight_cells)
```

However, this gives ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all(). What would be the appropriate way to do the highlighting here?

I was able to highlight the cells with null values only using

```
value_matrix_classification.style.highlight_null(null_color = "gray")
```

I am attaching the screenshot here just for the convenience of the reader.
[image]

How can I highlight all the cells based on the given categories: low, medium and high?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`apply` takes an entire row or column as input. Use `applymap` instead.

See [this Pandas documentation section](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/style.html#Styler-Functions).

Edit: you'll also want `highlight_cells` to return just `f"background-color: {color}"`, not wrapped in a list.

Answer (score 2):

[`Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) + [`fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html) to create a Series of styles for each column is a more common approach to this type of problem:

```
def highlight_cells(x):
    return 'background-color: ' + x.map(
        # Associate Values to a given colour code
        {'high': 'red', 'medium': 'orange', 'low': 'yellow'}
    ).fillna('gray')  # Fill unmapped values with default


value_matrix_classification.style.apply(highlight_cells)
```

[image: styled table]

---

Each column is mapped to a new set of colour codes.

This is how the styles are determined using just the second column as a reference, but [`Styler.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.apply.html) will call on all columns in the subset:

```
value_matrix_classification.iloc[:, 1].map(
    {'high': 'red', 'medium': 'orange', 'low': 'yellow'}
)

AIM/CGE 2.0          ADVANCE_2020_WB2C            NaN
                     ADVANCE_2030_Price1.5C       NaN
                     ADVANCE_2030_WB2C            NaN
IMAGE 3.0.1          ADVANCE_2020_WB2C         yellow
                     ADVANCE_2030_WB2C         yellow
MESSAGE-GLOBIOM 1.0  ADVANCE_2020_WB2C         yellow
Name: (wind_off_share, Wind-offshore power generation), dtype: object
```

Then `fillna` is used to replace an unmapped values with a default. Note this is not a NaN repr, but rather the default for *any* value which does not appear in the mapping dictionary:

```
value_matrix_classification.iloc[:, 1].map(
    {'high': 'red', 'medium': 'orange', 'low': 'yellow'}
).fillna('gray')

AIM/CGE 2.0          ADVANCE_2020_WB2C           gray  # NaN replaced with gray
                     ADVANCE_2030_Price1.5C      gray
                     ADVANCE_2030_WB2C           gray
IMAGE 3.0.1          ADVANCE_2020_WB2C         yellow
                     ADVANCE_2030_WB2C         yellow
MESSAGE-GLOBIOM 1.0  ADVANCE_2020_WB2C         yellow
Name: (wind_off_share, Wind-offshore power generation), dtype: object
```

Lastly, add the css property:

```
'background-color: ' + value_matrix_classification.iloc[:, 1].map(
    {'high': 'red', 'medium': 'orange', 'low': 'yellow'}
).fillna('gray')
```

```
AIM/CGE 2.0          ADVANCE_2020_WB2C           background-color: gray  # valid css style
                     ADVANCE_2030_Price1.5C      background-color: gray
                     ADVANCE_2030_WB2C           background-color: gray
IMAGE 3.0.1          ADVANCE_2020_WB2C         background-color: yellow
                     ADVANCE_2030_WB2C         background-color: yellow
MESSAGE-GLOBIOM 1.0  ADVANCE_2020_WB2C         background-color: yellow
Name: (wind_off_share, Wind-offshore power generation), dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

To add more detail, suppose you have

```
np.random.seed(0)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(4,2), columns=list('AB'))

>>> df

   A         B
0 -0.686760 -0.791461
1 -0.497699 -1.287310
2  0.793787  0.525824
3  0.501172  1.695914
```

To understand what is happening, we compare a column against a value=0.2. A column of booleans is returned. This is true for `and, or, not, if, while`. When you have multiple criteria, you will get multiple columns returned.

```
>>> df.B > 0.2

0     True
1     True
2    False
3    False
Name: B, dtype: bool
```

Now lets do comparsion

```
 if df.B > 0.2:
   print("do something")

 >>> ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

The above comparison is equal to the case below and not clear what the result should be.Should it be True because it’s not zero-length? False because there are False values? It is unclear, so instead, pandas raises a ValueError:

```
if Series([True, True, False, False]) > 0.2:
     print("do something")
```

So we need to get those multiple values into a single bool value, depending on what we want to do.

```
if pd.Series([True, True, False, False]).any(): # evaluates to True
   print("I checked if there was any True value in the Series!)

>>> I checked if there was any True value in the Series!

if pd.Series([True, True, False, False]).all(): # Evaluates to False
   print("I checked if there were all True values in the Series!")
```